# does my port of entry have to be the place in the annotated section of my b1/b2 visa?

Tags: b1-b2-visas

I was recently issued a B1/B2 visa with an annotation that i am going there to sit for an exam on 5th feb in Atlanta.  my visa has an issue date of october.
I am planning on going to the US in early January. Does my port of entry have to be Atlanta or may i go to some other place like chicago and later go to atlanta for my exam .

Comment: You have a bigger problem: You might not have mentioned to the embassy that you planned a trip to the US in January, the month before your exam. [In this circumstance](https://web.archive.org/web/20160422170005/http://blogs.usembassy.gov/philippines/visa-annotation-niv/) the embassy could cancel your visa, or an immigration officer could refuse entry to you.

Comment: I don’t think that is a problem . Cause I applied for a visa in October . And all the embassy asked me was the purpose to go to US and I said it was for my exam . They have issued me a visa from October and with an expiry date of April . So I am allowed to go to the states in any months between October to April . Also as many people told me the annotation is just about the purpose of my visit . Not restricting me to any state .